# php:pdo utf8mb4 configuration error on ubuntu?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, pdo, ubuntu-12.04

I have a mysql database with all tables set to utf8_bin. A table on it has two fields set again to utf8_bin. I've created a stored procedure : `SELECT name,id FROM tools WHERE valid=1 AND source in (1,2,3) AND name LIKE CONCAT('%',inValue,'%') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci LIMIT 100;`
I'm using the query for a search field to get all possible tools (eg. "sc" return Screwdriver, SCRewdriver , somethingscrew).
The query works well on a wampserver installation under window 7. I tried to import the database on Ubuntu 12.04 and the stored procedure doesn't return anything. 
If I run the query in it, I get results. If I run the stored procedure on phpmyadmin I get a weird error:

```
#1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
```

I have nowhere set utf8mb4. I also don't understand why I can't run the sql query on my PHP code that run flawlessy on Windows.

This is the code:

```
$q = "call getTools(?)";
$ing = "%$tll%";
try {
     $statement = self::$_conn->prepare($q);
 $statement->bindParam(1,$ing);
 $statement->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
}
/* fetch values */
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
  //printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $idIng);        
  array_push($return,array('label'=>$row[0],'value'=>$row[0],'id'=>$row[1]));
}
return json_encode($return);
```

Note that the try/catch was added later in order to understand why it didn't work. I strongly suspect the problem is with PDO or its configuration under Ubuntu 12.04.

on the constructor I define utf8

```
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$server;charset=utf8";
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Edit : table creation script

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tools`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `tools` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `valid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0= invalid 1=valid',
  `source` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '1=wikibooks 2 hand 3 hand similar',
  `parent` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'similar tool.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6206 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='1=wikibooks 2 hand 3 hand sim';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Edit: Added a line to allow exception in PDO. (doh)

```
self::$_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

as a result, I get an error on my php script:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

The table is NOT latin1.

Comment: Quite apparently the table/column was created with `utf8mb4`, not `utf8`. Where's your table creation script/what's the current table definition?

Comment: Added the creation script. It's a mysqldump from the working one. I still believe it's a pdo issue.

Comment: Which version of Mysql are install on your local and Unbuntu environment ?

Comment: It is now working. I haven't used it since my original message, but I did some update on ubuntu, so that might be the reason.